# Regex filter list of url's

Tags: regex

I need some help with a regex to filter a large list of urls, like:

```
/page-to-search-for/id/any-string
```

The problem is that the list also includes url's with a sub-page, like

```
/page-to-search-for/id/any-string/registration-form
```

Those pages needs to be excluded from the results.

So, the regex needs to like somewhat like:

```
/page-to-search-for\/(\d+)\/(\w+)(\/?(?!registration-form))
```

Unfortunately, the last part isn't working.

Hopefully someone can help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Try  `some-page\/(\d+)(\/[^\/]+)?$` if *any-string* is optional. If *any-string* is obligatory - `some-page\/(\d+)\/([^\/]+)$`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. The only thing is that all urls ending with "registration-form" needs to be excluded from the results...

Comment: The try [`some-page\/(\d+)\/([^\/]+)(?:\/(?!registration-form$).*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/Uy54Jw/1). It is not quite clear what to do with `/some-page/12/`.

Comment: Your regex works, awesome. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to block any URLs that, right after *any-string*, have `registration-form` at the end of string position.

You may use

```
some-page\/(\d+)\/([^\/]+)(?:\/(?!registration-form$).*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uy54Jw/1).

I suggest replacing `\w` with `[^\/]+` (to match any subpart, 1+ chars other than `/`) and the `(?:\/(?!registration-form$).*)?$` will match:

- `(?:\/(?!registration-form$).*)?$` - 1 or 0 (optionally) sequences of:

  - `\/`  - a slash
  - `(?!registration-form$)`  - not followed with `registration-form` and end of string (`$`)
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `$` - end of string.